# How to find element in a tensor that matches a substring

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a case where I need to know what prefix is in the filename that examples are drawn from during train time.

In my dataset generator, I have a tensor of the current filename `'sourceA_stuff.tfrecords'` or `'sourceB_stuff.tfrecords'`, etc. I want to determine which element in a tensor `sources = ['sourceA', 'sourceB']` matches the prefix of the filename, and pass the index of that element along as a source label. I'm having issues doing this without eager execution, and I really don't want to use eager execution if it can be avoided. Minimal example follows (see note at bottom):

```
filename = tf.cast('sourceA_stuff.tfrecords', tf.string)
sources = ['sourceA', 'sourceB']
for i in range(len(sources)):
    if sources[i] in filename:
        source = tf.cast(i, tf.int32)
        break
```

> TypeError: Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is enabled. To iterate over this tensor use `tf.map_fn`.

Problem is I can't figure out how to use `tf.map_fn` to basically emulate a `where` query with substring matching, and I can't figure out a good way to get around doing what I am trying to do without iteration.

Also tried:

```
source = [i for i in range(len(sources)) if source[i] in filename]
```

Same deal.

Note: having trouble testing this on my computer right now. Will update with fixes if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work.

```
import tensorflow as tf

filename = tf.cast('sourceB_stuff.tfrecords', tf.string)
sources = tf.constant(['sourceA.+', 'sourceB.+'])

tf_label = tf.argmax(tf.cast(tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.strings.regex_full_match(filename, x), sources, dtype=tf.bool), tf.int32))

with tf.Session() as sess:

  print(sess.run(tf_label))
```

Something to note:

- TensorFlow still doesn't have a `startswith()` type of string operation. So the closest I could find was `regex_full_match` meaning you'd need to have a regex that matches the **full** string you're comparing to.